# problem with disappearing elements in loop

Tags: python, selenium

```
users = driver.find_elements_by_name('value')
for users1 in users:
    users1.click()
```

The loop ends at some point, in the console I noticed that when the loop breaks, the elements disappear for a fraction of a second, I would like the loop to run all the time, and when the elements disappear, I continued clicking on the users

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toceu.jpg)

Comment: When would the execution end and how?

Comment: What do you mean by _when the elements disappear, I continued clicking on the users_?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run loop all the time, you can use while loop. And when you click on the user, make it false so that while loop does not run anymore.

Comment: I'm very green, I don't know how to code it too much